# Bilinear upsample in theano?

Tags: image, interpolation, image-resizing, theano

I want to do a simple bilinear resize (not necessarily by an integer factor) in Theano.  For example, starting from a (32,3,64,64) tensor, I would like a (32,3,96,96) tensor, where each 64x64 has been rescaled by a factor of 1.5 using bilinear interpolation. What is the best way to do that?

I would like this to support arbitrary factors, not just 1.5 specifically.

Note: the operation on each 64x64 would be the same as what `skimage.transform.rescale (scale=1.5, order=1)` does.